# Implementing HTTP caching Etag feature using MD5 in ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: performance, http, asp.net-web-api

I was reading Google performance document about HTTP caching at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching, This document says that we should use ETags when possible. I am using ASP.NET Web Api 2.2. I am now trying to implement ETag in all of my public apis. I am thinking to implement ETag using MD5. I mean, I will hash the json response on each request using MD5. Is there any performance hit of using MD5.calculateHash on each request? My json response size are not too big(within the range of 1 to 20KB).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there will be a performance hit.  Calculating a hash takes time.  However, you may find that the cost of calculating that hash is not significant in comparison to the performance saved by transferring unchanged bytes over the wire to the client.

However, there is no guarantee that you will get a perf improvement with Etags.  It depends on many things.  Are you going to regenerate the Etag on the server on every request to compare it with the incoming request?  Or are you going to create a cache of etag values and invalidate them when the resource changes?

If you are going to regenerate the etag on every request then it is possible that the time spent pulling data from the database and formatting the representation will be significantly higher than the time it takes to send a few bytes over the wire.  Especially if the entire representation can fit in a single network packet.

The key here is to ask if you really need the performance gain of Etags and is it worth the cost of doing the implementation.  Setting cache control headers to enable client side private caching may give you all the benefits that you need without having to implement etags.

I have a number of posts that go into this subject in more detail:

- http://www.bizcoder.com/using-etags-and-last-modified-headers-to-improve-performance-with-http-conditional-requests
- http://bizcoder.com/implementing-conditional-request-handling-for-your-api

Comment: There is no database interaction. I am just hashing the response json using MD5 on each request and comparing it with IfNoneMatch header? What is the best way to do this? BTW, Google recommending to use ETags

Comment: @user960567 Well, if there is zero cost to generating the json response, then the cost of generating the hash is probably less than the cost of sending the bytes over the wire, so returning an Etag probably makes sense.

Comment: Darrel, Frankly, I am using Azure Redis Cache for all my public apis for X minutes. So, what I am doing first is checking redis cache for response, if exist(or not exist grab it from db) then take it and return the response with cache-control max-age=X minutes and ETag headers. Before sending the response check ETag with IfNoneMatch. If same the 304 otherwise 200. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: @user960567 Arguably the Redis Cache will not provide any benefit.  Max-age=x should eliminate any request to the server prior to the time x.  So by the time the server gets a request, the redis cache will have expired.  At which point, every server request will go to the database and we are left questioning how much value the Etag is actually bringing for the effort.  Personally, I wouldn't add the complexity of Etags until you can see activity in production that would benefit from them.

Comment: Redis cache is between all users and has nothing to do with  http client cache which is for single user. We are seeing huge improvement in our production by implementing Redis cache.

Comment: @user960567 Right. The redis cache would only be redundant if you had a shared HTTP cache, like nginx or Squid, sitting in front of your origin server.